# Is there a way to bookmark all tabs in Chrome for Android?

Tags: chrome-for-android

I have lots of open tabs in Chrome for Android. How can I bookmark/export all of them?

Comment: I don't think there are any other ways of bookmarking all tabs on Chrome for Android apart from Firelord's method :( You could help prioritise adding it as a feature by starring the Chromium issue which can be found here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1026222. You do have to login with your Google account but I believe that only Googlers can see it.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

1. Sync the opened tabs in Chrome for Android **with** **Chrome for PC**.
2. Once the sync is completed you would see the opened tabs of your Android under History section (click Tabs from Other Devices in left panel) in your Chrome for PC.
3. Thereafter, click the three dots line in the upper right panel, choose *Open all*. Make sure to close other tabs in your Chrome for PC.
4. Once all of them have loaded, right click on any tab and choose *Bookmark all tabs* (as reported by [Ed Rhee on CNET](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-bookmark-all-open-browser-tabs-at-once/)).

That's it. Since the two devices are now synced you can access those bookmarks on any device.